# Why does gconf-edit not work to change the GDM icon?

Tags: linux, gdm

So I have done some googling and experimenting to change the GDM icon (Ubuntu 10.04) and have found the following ways:

1. UbuntTweak
2. Replace `/usr/share/icons/LoginIcons/apps/64/computer.svg` with your own svg
3. Change the gconf config setting `/apps/gdm/simple-greeter/logo_icon_name` to be the name of your icon in the theme.  Then copy that file to the icon theme path: `/usr/share/icons/LoginIcons/apps/64/`.

I have gotten #1 and #2 to work.  I am not sure how UbuntuTweak is actually doing it's magic (but would love to know).  I do not like #2 as it seems messy and what not.

I can *not* get #3 to work.  I have found post after post that says it should.  I have tried editing the gconf DB in multiple ways:

1. `gksu gconf-editor`
2. `gksu -u gdm gconf-editor`
3. `sudo -u gdm gconftool-2 --set --type string /apps/gdm/simple-greeter/logo_icon_name MYICONFILE`
4. `sudo gconftool-2 --set --type string /apps/gdm/simple-greeter/logo_icon_name MYICONFILE`

And while all of those methods show that the value has been edited NONE of them actually change the icon (did a `service gdm restart` to check).

Given that:

1. The official docs state that this should work
2. By replacing the `computer.svg` file it does work (so I know I am copying my file to the correct path)

I am completly confused as to why this doesn't work.  I know I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/LoginIcons/apps/64/
```

or wherever your icon is placed

Answer (score 0):

According to the official GDM Doc for GDM 2.32, the Gconf value edition only works if the user "gdm" has a $HOME directory to write and read theses parameters :

http://library.gnome.org/admin/gdm/2.32/gdm.html#greeterconfiguration

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the parameters here?